# Pass environment variable from external env file to container using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a docker-compose file which has a service that runs a postgres database image. The environment variables for the database (user, password, db_name) are in a env file called `db.env`:

```
DB_USERNAME=some_user
DB_PASSWORD=thepassword
DB_NAME=database
```

As I want to have these variables only in one file I wanted to use this `backand/db.env` file. The problem is, that the environemnt variable names differ from the ones which are used by postgres (DB_USERNAME <=> POSTGRES_USER).

This is the `docker-compose.yml`  file:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file: 
      - backend/db.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_TEST}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_DATABASE}
```

I tried to use the same approach as when using the standard `.env` file: [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

Comment: So there is no possibility to use the variables from an .env file (here backend/db.env) other than the default .env file?

Comment: off course you can use db.env but ENV name should be matched with postgress environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`env_file` will be available in the container `.env` in compose file itself so you need to use `.env` here

Workaround:

```
for i in $(cat < db.env); do export $i;done && docker-compose up -d
```

db.env:

```
DB_USERNAME=some_user
DB_PASSWORD=thepassword
DB_NAME=database
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you define Environment variable again once you defined in db.env? You can utilize the same `db.env`. Just set Environment variables name in db.env according to Postgres environment variable name, you can fine [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) .

db.env

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_DB=db
```

and docker compose

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file: 
      - db.env
```

`docker-compose up` and then try to verify DB and user

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash -c "psql -U user -l"
```

output

```
docker-user$  docker exec -it postgress-env_db_1 bash -c "psql -U user -l"
                             List of databases
   Name    | Owner | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | Access privileges 
-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------
 db        | user  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres  | user  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | user  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/user          +
           |       |          |            |            | user=CTc/user
 template1 | user  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/user          +
           |       |          |            |            | user=CTc/user
(4 rows)
```

Or if you want the same env then you can pass like

```
(export $(cat db.env | xargs) && docker-compose up )
```

Comment: The reason why I didn't do it like this was that I wanted to keep the current format of the db.env file. But yeah would be an option to change that, thanks.

Comment: @Adiii `cat db.env | docker-compose up` will not work you will always recieve `WARNING: The DB_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string`